# Guard + cucumber => custom guard file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, guard

I'm trying to correctly setup my [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard#readme) file in order to normally only run [cucumber](https://github.com/guard/guard-cucumber/blob/master/README.md) features that are in progress. Then, once they have completed, I want to run all of my features (manually). I have modified my guard file to have this, but the run_all isn't working. It just runs the @wip features.

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--no-profile --tags @wip --format 'pretty'", :run_all => { :cli => "--no-profile --color --format 'progress' --strict" } do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end
```

How does the :run_all method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up having to define the format for each.

```
guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--no-profile --tags @wip --format 'pretty'", :run_all => { :cli => "--no-profile -f Cucumber::Formatter::Fuubar features" } do
  watch(%r{^features/.+\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^features/support/.+$})          { 'features' }
  watch(%r{^features/step_definitions/(.+)_steps\.rb$}) { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'features' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run everything BUT @wip, you need to add ~@wip

Comment: The first cli is working as expected (I want to run @wip). Its the run_all that I'm having an issue with. I want to run everything with and without tags.